Assuming malloc succeeds, what could be a potential memory-related issue in this code?
Consider the following code snippet for inserting a node at the end of a singly linked list. Assuming malloc succeeds, what could be a potential memory-related issue in this code?
struct Node {     
    int value;     
    struct Node* next; 
}; 

void insertEnd(struct Node** head, int value) {    
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    
    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    struct Node* temp = *head;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newNode;
}


Invalid pointer access due to incorrect assignment of temp->next = new_node.
Segmentation fault due to temp->next not being existent in memory.
Memory leak due to not deallocating head after new_node insertion.
Segmentation fault due to head being NULL.
Memory error due to improper use of parameter in malloc.
The head of the linked list is not always correct for non-empty cases.

The correct answer of this question because there is an issue that there are no correct answer

C != C#. Fixed the tag for you.

Is this an exam / interview question, which you have pasted here?

In C you really should not cast the result of malloc.

@Ngân Nguyễn Thị Tuyết The problem with the code is that it will not compile.:) The structure Node does not have the data member data.:)

One of the items in the numbered list is likely to happen in one case. There are also other cases which are not listed, including some which are out of the control of the insertEnd function and which can't really be checked by it.

You have failed to fully check #4

@Ngân Nguyễn Thị Tuyết It seems the author of this test means that head can be equal to NULL as a result there will be a "segmentation fault due to head being NULL.". However the function should not check whether head is equal to NULL. It is the user of the function that shall provide a non-null pointer.

To summarize: Item #4 in the numbered list is the likely answer. But there are many more cases the original author of the question have either missed, or neglected to mention.

Compile time error, because newNode->data should be newNode->value. struct Node does not have a data member.

The numbered items refer to new_node; the code uses newNode.


Segmentation fault due to head being NULL.

If I call that function like this:
insertEnd(NULL, 5);

The line
if (*head == NULL) {

Attempts to dereference a NULL pointer. What happens next is undefined behaviour, but, on modern operating systems, will most likely terminate the program with violent prejudice.
Note that this is not necessarily incorrect behaviour. If you aren't allowed to change the API so that the function returns a success or fail value, there really isn't anything else sensible you can do.
